# Как разделить текст на русском на предложения и слоги?

Tags: python, текст

На вход подается произвольный текст, например,

> день весенний наступил кот на крыше завопил скоро тоже завоплю замуж очень я хочу

Мне нужно его разбить на предложения -

> день весенний наступил. кот на крыше завопил. скоро тоже завоплю. замуж очень я хочу.

Смотрел NLTK - но он вроде такого с русским текстом сделать не сможет?

Со слогами планирую вот [этот](https://github.com/spoterianski/poslogam/blob/master/rbs.py) скрипт использовать.
Может, как-то по количеству слог можно предложения бить?

Comment: Для начала формализуйте процесс разбиения на предложения. Почему именно так, а не иначе.

Comment: стихи так себе, конечно...

Comment: вы "произвольный текст" откуда берете? там никакого перевода строки не было, случайно?

Comment: @Jack_oS пользователь говорит их голосом, голос преобразуется в текст - уже без интонаций, ударений и т.п.

Comment: @LA_ Если фразы совсем произвольные, то это очень непростая задача, мне кажется. Нормально сами слова распознать и то будет непросто.

Answer (score 2):

Если структура предложений более-менее стабильная, вот как у вас глаголом вроде все предложения заканчиваются и этот глагол в предложении единственный, тогда можно взять `pymorphy2`, найти глаголы и вуаля:

```
import pymorphy2

text = "день весенний наступил кот на крыше завопил скоро тоже завоплю замуж очень я хочу"

ma = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
phrases = []
phrase = []
for word in text.split():
    phrase.append(word)
    if ma.parse(word)[0].tag.POS == 'VERB':
        phrases.append(' '.join(phrase).capitalize() + '.')
        phrase = []
print(' '.join(phrases))
```

Вывод:

```
День весенний наступил. Кот на крыше завопил. Скоро тоже завоплю. Замуж очень я хочу.
```

Но в более общем случае это задача для очень продвинутых нейросетей, на мой взгляд, предложения на русском языке могут быть очень заковыристыми.

Comment: Кстати, хорошая идея, но боюсь, сработает только для немецкого языка :-). Вот где строгий порядок предложений, от которого сначала так плющит всех русско- (до и англо- ) говорящих, оказывает неоценимую помощь.

Comment: @passant Ну, на данных автора вопроса же идеально работает. А если у него есть другие данные - пусть покажет, будем думать )

Answer (score 1):

Если стихи -  изучайте филологию, там есть какие-то правила, сколько в какой строке должно быть слогов (ямб, хорей, дактиль, анапест и пр.) Не всегда, но может сработать. Для произвольных строк - вряд-ли даже в теории этот возможно.